# Can´t run .bat file under windows 10

Tags: batch-file

I have few `.bat` files that I used under Windows XP. Now I want to use them under Windows 10, but when I run one of the files (even as administrator) it shows the command prompt screen for 1 second and nothing happens.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: This is lacking a lot of information. We need to see what your BAT script is doing, any errors that appear in the console window, etc. For example, if you just open a command prompt, then execute your bat file in the existing window, is anything printed?

Comment: Try renaming your .bat file and launching it again.

Comment: @Jonas curious what you are thinking here, what in the file name could cause this issue?

Comment: @vcsjones: I personally chose to think of the lack of information *as* the issue.  :)
I even considered changing 2 words in the title to reflect such, but thought that might be too far.

Comment: This is a question like: "my car doesn't work, please tell me what's wrong with it", without ever showing the car... I'm voting to close this post...

Comment: @Scott For example if you were to ping yahoo.com... in a .bat file called "ping.bat" and run it on XP it will work, however running "Ping.bat" on windows 10 will cause it to loop.Therefore renaming the file will allow it to function properly.

Comment: Makes sense.  Seems unlikely though, especially with multiple (few) files having the same issue.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I copied some .bat files to a new Windows 10 installation. Figured out that the encoding got changed when it was opened for edit. Just changed the encoding to UTF-8 (from Notepad++) and it worked fine after that.

Comment: a simple work: in my system, the .bat file was in a path like this: C:\Doc\Path To File. I changed it to: C:\Doc\Path_To_File. The .bat file now works.

Answer (score 14):

There is no inherent reason that a simple batch file would run in XP but not Windows 10.  It is possible you are referencing a command or a 3rd party utility that no longer exists.  To know more about what is actually happening, you will need to do one of the following:

- Add a `pause` to the batch file so that you can see what is happening before it exits.

  1. Right click on one of the `.bat` files and select "edit".  This will open the file in notepad.
  2. Go to the very end of the file and add a new line by pressing "enter".
  3. type `pause`.
  4. Save the file.
  5. Run the file again using the same method you did before.

**- OR -**

- Run the batch file from a static command prompt so the window does not close.

  1. In the folder where the `.bat` files are located, hold down the "shift" key and right click in the white space.
  2. Select "Open Command Window Here".
  3. You will now see a new command prompt.  Type in the name of the batch file and press enter.

Once you have done this, I recommend creating a new question with the output you see after using one of the methods above.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I copied some .bat files to a new Windows 10 installation. Figured out that the encoding got changed when it was opened for edit. Just changed the encoding to UTF-8 (from Notepad++) and it worked fine after that.

Comment: Thanks, @Shiyaz.  That was the answer.  Seems "PowerShell" defaults to saving UTF-16!?  Serves me right for not using Cygwin.

Comment: On top of the encoding, I would also want to add the possible "invisible" or non-standard characters (e.g. MS quotes or long dashes) that might be a result of copy/paste. You will definetely "see" these characters in smart editors or source-control tools.
These will possibly make your scripts non-executable or malfunctioning.

Comment: @BrockAdams file system's current format