# VBA Open batch file - window closes immediately after executing

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file

I am trying to automate the execution of a batch file using VBA. I tried using the code below to execute. When I run this it opens a cmd window and then immediately closes. Any suggestions?

```
Sub openbatchfile()

    path = "C:\HedgeRxConnect\CTAUpload.bat"
    Call shell(path, vbNormalNoFocus)

End Sub
```

When I run it manually below is what appears on the cmd window. It opens up a proxy server authentication which requests my log in credentials. Is there anyway to automate my login details for this?

```
C:\HedgeRxConnect>C:
C:\HedgeRxConnect>HRxCImport.exe  JobConfig_FixedWidthCTAImport_CTA.xml
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Does _"When I run it manually"_ means running bat file in cmd window or by double clicking  in window? May refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208011/can%c2%b4t-run-bat-file-under-windows-10)

Comment: Hi there, yes i am referring to double clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

Automate? What is the frequency of batch file executions? If you need to run whenever windows starts, you can use regedit in the Run key to automatically run batch. If the frequency is hourly you can use the windows task scheduler.